# There are no syntax error still the php file doesnt write

Tags: php, html, forms

I trierd running the files on the server still the php wont write on text file, I've added html form and php screenshot below.
[contact.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPehC.png)

Form.html

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" name="contact-form" id="contact-form">

                          <ul>

                          <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.4s">
                                <label for="contact-name">Name :</label>
                                <div class="textarea">
                                      <input type="text" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" value="" required>
                                </div>
                          </li>

                          <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.6s">
                                <label for="contact-email">Email :</label>
                                <div class="textarea">
                                      <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" value="" required>
                                </div>
                          </li>

                          <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.6s">
                                <label for="contact-project">Message :</label>
                                <div class="textarea">
                                      <textarea type="text" name="contact-project" id="contact-project" rows="6" value="" required>
                                      </textarea>
                                </div>
                          </li>

                          </ul>

                          <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="contact-submit" id="contact-submit" class="send wow fadeInUp">Send Message</button>

                          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['contact-submit']))
```